# IndexOf not working with date tolocalestring in ie but ie supports it

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

So I have some code which works on other browsers but in IE it's not working.
I can confirm by logging output to the browser that the indexOf function is supported and working because the `console.log('array.indexOf(2) = ' + array.indexOf(2));` code outputs 0 in the console.

According to my logging output other values are correct and everything looks like it should work, but the code inside the if statement is never hit.

Here is an image of my javascript logging to the console
[image: Here is an image of my javascript logging to the console]

I tried numerous things, which I have highlighted in the code like using `.toString()` and `jQuery.inArray` and also `daySetting[0].includes`

```
console.log('daySetting[0] = ' + daySetting[0]);

console.log('new Date().toLocaleString("en-us", { weekday: "short" }) = ' + new Date().toLocaleString('en-us', { weekday: 'short' }));

console.log('daySetting[0].indexOf(new Date().toLocaleString("en-us", { weekday: "short" })) = ' + daySetting.indexOf(new Date().toLocaleString('en-us', { weekday: 'short' })));

var array = [2, 9, 9]; //test array
console.log('array.indexOf(2) = ' + array.indexOf(2));

if (daySetting[0].toString().indexOf(new Date().toLocaleString('en-us', { weekday: 'short' })) !== -1) {
  //|| daySetting[0].includes(new Date().toLocaleString('en-us', { weekday: 'short' }))//tried the includes method and .toString() method
  //if (jQuery.inArray(new Date().toLocaleString('en-us', { weekday: 'short' }), daySetting) != -1) {//tried jquery in array
  console.log("dayHours = " + dayHours); //expecting this to be output
  continue; //code is inside a loop
}
```

I expect to see the code `console.log("dayHours = " + dayHours);` to be logged to the console but it is not.
This works fine in other browsers but I just can't figure out what's going on.

Here is a fiddle of the code https://jsfiddle.net/q8pod2xj/1/

Comment: @SudhakarRS I confirmed indexOf is working, check this code ```var array = [2, 9, 9];console.log('array.indexOf(2) = ' + array.indexOf(2));``` which outputs 0 in the browser console logging

Comment: oh.yeah.it's working

Comment: Please add a [mcve] that shows the actual problem.

Comment: @SudhakarRS yeah it's odd because as far as I can see it should work

Comment: @chrisc kindly post your daySetting array for us

Comment: @SudhakarRS I added fiddle at bottom of question

Comment: @Andreas I added fiddle at bottom of question

Comment: _"Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included **in the question itself**"_ - A link to an external resource, that may be unavailable for whatever reason, should be the last option.

Comment: hmm jsfiddle doesn't work for me in ie

Comment: Notice how in ie this bit of code is not output to the console ```console.log("dayHours = " + dayHours);```, of course I'm out of time and gotta leave the office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem isn't with indexOf.

new Date().toLocaleString('en-us', { weekday: 'short' }) returns ' Thu' (length=4), has a space in 0th index. Avoided it using substr(1).

```
var theHours = "Mon: Open 9am - 5:30pm, Tues: Open 9am - 5:30pm, Wed: Open 9am - 5:30pm, Thurs: Open 9am - 5:30pm, Fri: Open 9am - 5:30pm, Sat: Open 9am - 5pm, Sun: Open 11am - 5pm";
var days = theHours.split(',');
for (var i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
    var daySetting = days[i].split(/:(.+)/);
    var dayHours = daySetting[1];

    if (daySetting[0].indexOf(new Date().toLocaleString('en-us', { weekday: 'short' }).substr(1)) !== -1) {
        console.log("dayHours = " + dayHours); //expecting this to be output
        continue; //code is inside a loop
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sudhakar RS I can see now it is working as expected, I would have never expected that space in the 0th to affect indexOf as it should still match it. Do you know why that is? Thanks for your help :)